# How I can keep track of all the functions defined with a macro to later call them all at once?

Tags: c++

I have the following code to define new functions by using a macro

```
#include <iostream>

#define CONCAT(x, y) x##y
#define PREFIX_COUNTER(prefix, counter) CONCAT(prefix, counter)
#define FUNC() void PREFIX_COUNTER(func_, __COUNTER__)()

FUNC() {
    std::cout << "first func" << std::endl;
}

FUNC() {
    std::cout << "second func" << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char **) {
    func_0();
    func_1();
    return 0;
}
```

Each call to `FUNC` will define a new function like `func_0`, what I need to do now is to call to all the functions defined by func like this:

```
int main(int, char **) {
    CALL_ALL_FUNC(); // this will call func_0 and func_1
    return 0;
}
```

Could be possible to append the name of every new FUNC call into something like a vector so later I can iterate it? Does the preprocessor has something like that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You still need to define the function bodies; why not give them names yourself?

Comment: I want to make a test runner like catch, you just define functions with a macro and later in a different source file containing `main` you call them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Catch2 was mentioned, here is an example based off of the macros there.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Func;

std::vector<Func*> func_group;

struct Func {
    Func() {
        func_group.push_back(this);
    }

    virtual void action() = 0;
};

#define CONCAT(x, y) x##y
#define PREFIX_COUNTER(prefix, counter) CONCAT(prefix, counter)

#define UNIQUE_FUNC(id) \
    struct PREFIX_COUNTER(Func_, id) : public Func {\
        void action();\
    } PREFIX_COUNTER(func_instance_, id);\
    void PREFIX_COUNTER(Func_, id)::action()

#define FUNC() UNIQUE_FUNC(__COUNTER__)

FUNC() {
    std::cout << "first func" << std::endl;
}

FUNC() {
    std::cout << "second func" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    for (auto func : func_group)
        func->action();
    return 0;
}
```

- A new derived class is defined for each `FUNC` macro.
- It initializes itself and adds itself to a vector.
- The macro leads into defining the body of a function that can be called from the base class later. (`func->action()`).

Comment: thank you, but I just realized that I can't use `__COUNTER__ ` because any call to it by other code will increment it

Comment: I don't think other code could interfere with it here but you could probably use `__LINE__` just as well and it would be constant.

Comment: I see, __LINE__ is a good idea but the macro will be called in many different source files. So I think it could be possible to get collision in the name

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do some horrid things like the code below (just an outline of the idea). Should you really do it or not is up to you however.

```
static std::vector<std::function<void()>> g_vec;
class Reg
{
public:
    Reg(std::function<void()> f) { g_vec.push_back(f); }
};

// insert __declspec(selectany) for your compiler and do some better function passing around, maybe C style
#define FUN(x) void v##x(); inline static Reg r##x { []{ v##x(); } }; void v##x()
FUN(a)
{
    std::cout << "a\n";
}
FUN(b)
{
    std::cout << "b\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for (auto& f : g_vec)
        f();
}
```

Comment: thank you! this is nice! but... how I can do something like `FUN("string with spaces")` ?

Comment: @ellipticaldoor what do you intend to do with the string you pass into `FUN()`? Can you provide an example?

Comment: if you want FUN("string with spaces") than you can't easily, but you can use _COUNTER_ as a hidden parameter for example, like you do in your original question for example. you just need to force the preprocessor to generate you a unique name for your generated function, something that will be valid after macro concat (##), you may just add a second param to a FUN macro - function name. But it's all just macro stuff and be aware that the preprocessor is dumb enough and do only text copypasting, so if you have some rule for function names (no spaces i.e), it's up to you not to break it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do here, but I don't think that a macro is the correct approach.

`__COUNTER__` increments every time it appears, so you can't ever actually check how many functions are defined (as the number will keep incrementing). Likewise, if you (or a library) uses it elsewhere, there isn't any way to tell how many functions were created and how many times `__COUNTER__` was incremented by something else.

A possible alternative solution to your problem is to create an `std::vector` of *function pointers*. You can also combine this with lambda expressions and wrap it in a singleton or a static class to get somewhat close to what you want to define:

```
//DynamicFunctions.h
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class DynamicFunctions {
public:
    static void add(std::function<void()> const& function) {
        _functions.push_back(function);
    };

    static void call(int index) {
        //TODO: range checking
        _functions[index]();
    }

    static void runAll() {
        for (auto const& func : _functions) {
            func();
        }
    };

private:
    static std::vector<std::function<void()>> _functions;
};

std::vector<std::function<void()>> DynamicFunctions::_functions = std::vector<std::function<void()>>();
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "DynamicFunctions.h"

int main() {
    DynamicFunctions::add([]() { std::cout << "Functions[0]" << std::endl; });
    DynamicFunctions::add([]() { std::cout << "Functions[1]" << std::endl; });
    DynamicFunctions::add([]() { std::cout << "hi!" << std::endl;});

    DynamicFunctions::call(2);

    DynamicFunctions::runAll();

    return 0;
}
```

This way, whenever you needed to create a dynamic function, instead of using the macro you would call `DynamicFunctions::add`. To run a function, instead of calling `func_0`, you would pass that index to `DynamicFunctions::call(0)`. This way, as it's all stored in a `std::vector`, you can easily iterate through them when you need to call `DynamicFunctions::runAll`

Comment: FWIW the `Catch` source code is available on GitHub at https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2. Although it's obscured away through macros, it would appear they take a similar approach - `TEST_CASE` aliases to `INTERNAL_CATCH_TESTCASE`, which aliases to `INTERNAL_CATCH_TESTCASE2`, which then handles the method declaration and registering it. Relevant source file appears to be this one: https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/ed02710b83c2a3ddbca20b86f3d26d2fb99d2d02/src/catch2/internal/catch_test_registry.hpp

Comment: But with this it seems that I can only call `add` inside the body of the main function, which defeats the purpose